# how to search data in mongodb for nested object

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have an object below.

```
{
    "_id" : "8LEfPt57rWHZ8ebdS",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-04-07T16:00:30.798Z"),
    "services" : {
        "password" : {
            "bcrypt" : "$2a$10$SIUgFIWTq6nBmTIqNjMYFOSKtds.yR26fm8yblbcRm3yYeg.rH3jK"
        },
        "resume" : {
            "loginTokens" : [
                {
                    "when" : ISODate("2015-04-07T16:00:30.992Z"),
                    "hashedToken" : "Qnq4m/ETqI/heHPIYGdAJIyYQJNQ0EH5MFgDjgQt2GY="
                },
                {
                    "when" : ISODate("2015-04-09T14:49:08.652Z"),
                    "hashedToken" : "xxm3xXggjT1v8vcaY4/uLXUtPdMKyXaPp7xCLF6gBeM="
                }
            ]
        }
    },
}
```

I want to get the list of users,who has logged in a date range .

But I am not getting any result for below query.

```
db.users.find({ 'services.resume.loginTokens': { $elemMatch: { when:  { '$lte': '2015-04-11T18:29:59.999Z', '$gte': '2015-04-04T18:29:59.999Z' } } } })
```

Can anyone will help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Mongo [aggregation pipline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) and mongo aggregation [$and](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/and/) operator will find your exact result. Check below query

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
    "$unwind": "$services.resume.loginTokens"
}, {
    "$match": {
    "$and": [{
        "services.resume.loginTokens.when": {
            "$lt": ISODate("2015-04-11T18:29:59.999Z")
        }
    }, {
        "services.resume.loginTokens.when": {
            "$gt": ISODate("2015-04-04T18:29:59.999Z")
        }
    }]
    }
}).pretty()
```

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple.. You have to put ISODate format date to check in query, because you are having date in ISO format  in DB and its not a string , you can write this type of query for strings, so

Replace your query

```
db.users.find({ 'services.resume.loginTokens': { $elemMatch: { when: { '$lte': '2015-04-11T18:29:59.999Z', '$gte': '2015-04-04T18:29:59.999Z' } } } })
```

to this

```
db.dummy.find({ 'services.resume.loginTokens': 
{ $elemMatch: { when: { $lte: ISODate('2015-04-11T18:29:59.999Z'), $gte: ISODate('2015-04-04T18:29:59.999Z') } } } }) 
// added ISOdate()
```